# Sent actions Selector not applyable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having some issues using Xcode, I do have my .xib file containing two help buttons. But, I can't or don't know how to apply a selector on those.

[image: panPref]

Here you see the .xib, containing the two help buttons. But, when I right click on those,

[image: rightClick]

I can't click on the + sign on the Sent Actions : Selector field.

My method are already written, aka

- (IBAction) helpTree:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) helpType:(id)sender;

How may I link these methods with those buttons ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-dragging from the Interface Builder to the implementation file.

Full instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/AboutConnectingObjectstoCode.html).